# View location of a document open in Preview

Tags: preview

I've got a PDF open in Preview (5.5.2) and I want to know where it is located in my filesystem. How can I find that out in Preview? In MS Word, there's a command called `Document Properties` which gives detailed information about the active document; I'm looking for an equivalent.

Aside: I've been able to do this in a roundabout fashion from the command-line by piping `lsof` through `grep` using an expression that contained a word in the document title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-Click on the title gives you the full path. This not only works in Preview but more or less in all applications (including Office).

[image]