# RMB menu on document title in Preview gone with Mavericks?

Tags: macos, preview

One of the greatest features OS X had (inherited from NextStep AFAIK) was the fact that the document name in a window's title could be right-clicked in order to get a drop-down menu with the parent folder hierarchy.  (This is also mentioned in [View location of a document open in Preview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58093/view-location-of-a-document-open-in-preview), but that still refers to the old method that no longer works with Preview 7.0 from Mavericks.)

However, after the update to Mavericks, this is no longer possible at least in the Preview app, which now shows a (much less useful) menu for renaming, tagging, and moving(?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself; thanks to your 'it should work' answers, I realized that it has to have something to do with the document itself.  Turns out that I had added this particular PDF to the 'Books' section of iTunes in the past, so the Mavericks update moved the PDF into the iBooks folder.

**The iBooks folder seems to be handled specially**, so that the discussed RMB menu does not appear on books opened in Preview.

One can still "move" the PDF to another location (e.g., using the new menu), which will (contrary to the old iTunes Books location) actually create a copy of the PDF, and then the secondary click menu works again.

Answer (score 0):

If you secondary-click the text for the title (and not the arrow next to it), it should still open the menu:

[image]

Comment: ⌘-clicking also works.

Comment: No, I tried both, and it does not work here.  OS X 10.9.2, Preview 7.0 (826.4) according to the about dialog.  Alt-Click opens the new drop-down menu starting at the small "arrow"/triangle, pressing Cmd/Ctrl lets the triangle disappear, but I won't get the desired menu shown (yes, I mean the one depicted in your screenshot).